# x86 opcode for pushing a string address onto the stack

Tags: opcode, hex-editors

I am changing an executable with a hex editor and I have to call a function and pass some text as a parameter. My code is in the .text section, and I've got my string encoded in the .data section below it. Say my string is "AAAA". The address of the string begins at "0x008000". I'm trying to push the string like so:

```
push [0x008000]    FF 35 00 08 00
call function      FF 15 11 11 11
```

The function call works with default NULL values, so I know I'm calling it correctly.

The problem is calling the opcode for it. I'm struggling with understanding the opcode format for the push. Is it possible to push the address of the string directly like this? I've opened my executable in IDA to get a better idea of how the existing code pushes strings, but I haven't been able to find a clear example of a string address being directly pushed to a stack. Most of the strings in the disassembled code are either stored on the local stack or called by a label which goes to an offset which gets something off the stack. I confess I don't really quite know how the labels work because there doesn't really seem to be a point where a string stored in memory and easily accessible is clearly pushed onto the stack.

Any explanations are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have the PUSH r/m format of the push instruction, which pushes a value from a register or loaded from memory -- in this case loaded from the address 0x800 -- assuming the next byte is 00, as it's a 6-byte instruction.

If you want to push the *value* 0x8000 (which you're going to treat as an address in your function), you need to use the PUSH immed32 instruction, which would be `68 00 80 00 00`  Note that this is one byte smaller than the PUSH r/m instruction, so you'll need to add a 1-byte NOP (`90`) either before or after, if you're trying to do a binary patch.

Comment: I'm trying to pass a string that I have stored in the .data section at 0x8000. I'm trying to push the address of that string to the stack. Is this the correct way to do pass a string parameter in assembly? I'm trying to figure out why my function isn't working.

Comment: Usually x86-32 (i386) code uses a flat 32-bit address space, with no segmentation, and all arguments are passed on the stack, so yes, that address would be passed as the value 0x8000 on the stack.